# What is the difference between a philosopher of science and a theoretical physicist?

Tags: soft-question

What is the characteristic **objective** difference in **objectively observable** attitudes and research styles between a philosopher of physics and a theoretical physicist?

Was Ernst Mach more of a philosopher of physics or a theoretical physicist? What about Niels Bohr? David Bohm? John Bell? Julian Barbour? John Wheeler? Max Tegmark? Albert Einstein?

The difference I am alluding to isn't about formal academic titles like which university department one belongs to, but the difference mentioned in the following quote by Albert Einstein:

> This independence created by philosophical insight is—in my opinion—the mark of distinction between a mere artisan or specialist and a real seeker after truth.

i.e. between an "artisan" and a "seeker", between a "rote symbol-pushing calculator" and a "contemplator".